# Kotlin - Issue Extending Kotlin String Class

Tags: android, string, kotlin, methods, extending

I am currently trying to extend Kotlins String class with a method in a file **StringExt.kt**

```
fun String.removeNonAlphanumeric(s: String) = s.replace([^a-ZA-Z0-9].Regex(), "")
```

But Kotlin in not allowing me to use this method in a lambda:

```
s.split("\\s+".Regex())
.map(String::removeNonAlphanumeric)
.toList()
```

The error is:

```
Required: (TypeVariable(T)) -> TypeVariable(R)
Found: KFunction2<String,String,String>
```

What confuses me about this is that Kotlins Strings.kt has very similar methods and
I can call them by reference without Intellij raising this kind of issue. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have declared an extension function that accepts an additional parameter and should be used as `s.replace("abc")`.

I think what you meant is the following:

```
fun String.removeNonAlphanumeric(): String = this.replace("[^a-ZA-Z0-9]".toRegex(), "")
```

This declaration doesn't have an extra parameter and uses `this` to refer to the `String` instance it is called on.

Comment: Thank you! This is absolutely correct :) Calling it as the below works as well: 

fun String.removeNonAlphanumeric() = replace("[^a-ZA-Z0-9]".toRegex(), "")

Answer (score 0):

I thing this is because a lambda is an anonymous function and dose not access to the scope of a extension file.

Check this link maybe contains some useful information:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html